# Get android device IMEI number using php

Tags: php

i want IMEI number using php program when android device access my php url.

Comment: Post what code you have tried.

Comment: i am trying first time to code, i have not coded anything

Comment: is it possible to get imei using php when device access url?

Comment: That is not possible at all without an app running on that device.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Corodova device API to get device UDID this can be used to send to server.

Comment: Note that I up voted this question when I should have down voted. While Cordova is awesome in it's way it is a specific technology that wasn't listed in the OPs question. Cordova can access any form of information on a device with the right permissions but that is a hybrid app issue (at least) not a web app issue.

Answer (score 1):

A server doesn't know anything about a connected client until the client sends it, in any case. Client data is typically provided by the browser within standard HTTP request headers. General purpose browsers don't send IMEI numbers, so no, this isn't possible in your typical Web App scenario where requests come from standard browsers which a web service has no control over.

Also note that a device's IMEI number isn't exposed to javascript in standard browsers either.